# Overall Progress of MapReduce Hadoop Job

Tags: java, api, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata

I've a mapreduce program in which I'm processing 1 file per mapper instance.
I don't have reducer code as of now.

Now, what I would like to have is to get some API to check the progress of overall mapreduce job ?

I see the `mapprogress()` method in API, but it gives a progress regarding the mapper. Can we get overall progress of the entire job ?

**Edit: I'm triggering this hadoop job through oozie workflow. Is it possible to show overall progress of the oozie or hue ? Do they have some API for it ?**

Answer (score 1):

A map-reduce job consist of two phases i.e. mapper phase and reducer phase.

The reducer phase is dependent on the mapper output and thus you cannot track the progress of reducer unless you are done with mapper execution. As reducer phase is dependent, you cannot fetch the progress of reducer before hand (which is required to get entire job status).

Rather what you can do is:

Use [`Job.mapProgress()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobStatus.html#mapProgress%28%29) to track the mapper task progress. Once it is complete, you can use [`Job.reduceProgress()`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.1.1/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobStatus.html#reduceProgress%28%29) to track your reducer progress (given you have reducers), which is eventually same as the progress of entire job.

Comment: @peeppeep : I have not used oozie or hue extensively. So cannot comment on that front.